# Husky pre-commit hook finishes after commit

Tags: node.js, husky

The following script was written in order to sort JSON files by key on pre-commit hook:

```
 /*
 * Will reorder all files in given path.
 */

const sortJson = require("sort-json");
const fs = require("fs");
const chalk = require("chalk");

const log = console.log;
const translationsPath = process.argv.slice(2).join(" ");

function readFiles(dirname) {
  try {
    return fs.readdirSync(dirname);
  } catch (e) {
    log(chalk.red(`Failed reading files from path; ${e}`));
  }
}

log(
  chalk.bgGreen(
    `Running json sort pre-commit hook on path: ${translationsPath}`
  )
);

const files = readFiles(translationsPath);
files.forEach((file) => {
  log(chalk.yellow(`Sorting ${file}...`));
  try {
    sortJson.overwrite(`${translationsPath}\\${file}`);
    log(chalk.green(`Finished sorting ${file}`));
  } catch (e) {
    log(chalk.red(`Failed sorting file ${file}; ${e}`));
  }
});

log(
  chalk.bgGreen(
    `Finished sorting files`
  )
);
```

I'm attaching the script to my `package.json` with `husky` precommit hook:

```
  "scripts": {
    "sort-translations": "node ./scripts/husky/json-sort src/assets/translations",
    ...
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run sort-translations"
    }
  },
```

The result is that the commit is finished, and only then the script finishes with the created unstage changes.
The script itself runs synchronously with the `Finished sorting files` message printed last.

My question is, how can I make it synchronous; first finish running `node ./scripts/husky/json-sort src/assets/translations`, then `git commit`.

Thanks!

Comment: Since this is merely a pre-commit hook it is safe to use `sync` functions . So if you use `fs.readdirSync()`, it should work. Using the `async` version will likely not improve anything in this scenario.

Comment: Thanks @adelriosantiago, I changed it to readdirSync(), but I still get the commit done before the files are changed. I'll edit my post with the new code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to @adelriosantiago comment, I figured it out.

1. First of all, I started using `readdirSync()` instead of `readdir()`. Then I was able to verify (through logging) that the script indeed ends only when the files are edited. Unfortunately that wasn't enough - the hook still ended with uncommitted files.
2. At this point I realized - it's not about the hook, it's about the git staging! The script ends it time, but the modified changes remain unstaged so they're not commited. So I've added  `&& git add src/assets/translations` to `pre-commit` hook.

Now everything works as desired.